# How can I run d3-cloud in node.js

Tags: node.js, d3.js, d3-cloud

I'm trying to get the node.js examples from [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) working.

I checked out the project

```
git clone https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud
```

then in that directory:

```
npm install
```

That seems to work.

Then:

```
$ node examples/node.js 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:803
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'
Require stack:
- /private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js' ]
```

I tried:

```
npm install canvas
```

That succeeded.

Then I ran it again:

```
$ node examples/node.js 
/private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js:11
    .canvas(function() { return new Canvas(1, 1); })
                                ^

TypeError: Canvas is not a constructor
    at /private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js:11:33
    at Object.cloud.start (/private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.js:34:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/fff/d3-cloud/examples/node.js:18:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11
```

I'm not a node person, so I'm kind of stuck here. There's a node in the [readme](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud), but I'm not sure how to act on it:

```
# canvas([canvas])

If specified, sets the canvas generator function, which is used internally to draw text. If not specified, returns the current generator function, which defaults to:

function() { return document.createElement("canvas"); }

When using Node.js, you will almost definitely override this default, e.g. using the canvas module.
```

Answer (score 0):

The last commit for `d3-cloud` was at least 3 years ago, and searching for "Canvas is not a constructor" led me to [this Github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/997) in the repository for the `node-canvas` plugin. That issue is from September 2017, which is again 3 years ago.

Around that time, `canvas` released their version 2.0.0, for which [their changelog](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200) reads

```
// (1) The Canvas constructor is no longer the default export from the module.
/* old: */
const Canvas = require('canvas')
const mycanvas = new Canvas(width, height)
/* new: */
const { createCanvas, Canvas } = require('canvas')
const mycanvas = createCanvas(width, height)
mycanvas instanceof Canvas // true
```

So my guess is you need to install version 1.6.9, the the latest in their `1.x` branch.

---

These problems arise often, especially when using older libraries. Take `d3` for example, which is now at 6.x, but has a lot of active coders use 3.x or even 2.x. There are tutorials and examples for everything, but the API has changed a lot in the meantime and reading release notes is essential for matching up all these versions. Hopefully, now you'll know where to look!

Answer (score 0):

I think your import statement is wrong. You have to import the `Canvas` class. This works for me. The implementation is referenced from https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/node.js and https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/144.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const { Canvas } = require('canvas')
const cloud = require('d3-cloud')

const words = ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this"]
  .map(function (d) {
    return {
      text: d,
      size: 10 + Math.random() * 90
    }
  })

cloud().size([960, 500])
  .canvas(function() {
    return new Canvas(1, 1)
  })
  .words(words)
  .padding(5)
  .rotate(function () {
    return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90;
  })
  .font("Impact")
  .fontSize(function (d) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .on("end", draw)
  .start()

function draw(words, bounds) {
  const { x: width, y: height } = bounds[1]
  
  const canvas = new Canvas(width, height, 'png')
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.textAlign = 'center'
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'

  for (let word of words) {
    ctx.font = `${word.size}px ${word.font}`
    ctx.fillText(word.text, (width / 2) + word.x, (height / 2) + word.y)
  }

  fs.writeFileSync('out.png', canvas.toBuffer())
}
```